# Find the maximum perpendicular height between a chord and an arc.

Tags: trigonometry, circles

I am doing a maths modelling project, and I am stuck on a part.

[image]

I have a (arc length) and L (chord length), but I want to find H, the maximum perpendicular distance between them!

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Note: I don't have the radius!
A way of getting the radius would be brilliant, but all I have is a and L!

Comment: See [sagitta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagitta_(geometry)).

Comment: ...Really useful, but we don't have the radius!

Comment: I have a formula but if you are trying to isolate H it does not look promising. You could still solve for H using iterative methods.

Comment: Try drawing the center. You will see $\theta$, and therefore $r$.

Comment: $(-1)$ for not thinking before commenting.

Answer (score 1):

Knowledge of $H$ and knowledge of the radius $r$ are equivalent, because $(r-H)^2+(\frac12 L)^2 = r^2$.  (There is a minor technical issue about this quadratic having two solutions for $H$ once you fix $r$, which I will ignore.)

Knowledge of the radius $r$ and knowledge of the central angle $\theta$ subtended by half the arc are equivalent, because $a=2r\theta$.

Finding out $\theta$ is tricky: from
\begin{align*} a &= 2r\theta \\ L &= 2r\sin\theta \end{align*}
we get
$$ \frac La = \frac{\sin\theta}{\theta} $$
and $\theta\in[0,\pi]$.  Now, the function on the RHS (called the sinc function) is strictly decreasing on $[0,\pi]$, so there is in fact just one value of $\theta$ in that interval that satisfies this equation; but I don't know how to find it except numerically.

Answer (score 0):

by using NEWTONS RAPHSON method we can find out the arc angle...

**A Real World Example**

The arc length (blue line AB) of a circle is 16 and its chord length (line AB) is 14. (Therefore arc AD = 8 and line AE = 7)
How can we solve for the other parts of the circle?
We can see from the graphic of the circle that:

Since both equations equal the radius AO, we then can say:

Rather than deal with two numbers, we'll let the letter 'n' equal the ratio of AE ÷ (arc AD).

Putting the equation in standard form we have:

Angle AOD can't be isolated because this is an implicit equation and requires Newton's Method to solve it.

We will need the derivative of f(x) which is:

```
f '(x) = cos ∠ AOD -n = 0
```

The value of n = (Chord AB / Arc AB) = (14 / 16) = .875

To start, let's guess that X ₀ (or angle AOD) is 1 radian.
X₁ = X₀ - [ f(X₀) ÷ f'(X₀) ]

X₁ = 1 - [ {(sin(1) -(n * 1)} / (cos(1) -n) ]

X₁ = 1 - [ {0.8414709848 -(.875*1)} / (0.54030230587 -.875) ]

X₁ = 1 - [ -0.03352901519 / -0.33469769413 ]

X₁ = 0.8998229872

X₂ = X₁ - [ sin(X₁) -(n * X₁) / cos(X₁) -n ]

X₂ = 0.8998229872 - [ {sin(0.8998229872) -(.875 * 0.8998229872)} / (cos(0.8998229872) -.875) ]

X₂ = 0.8998229872 - [ {0.7832168644 -0.7873451138} / (0.6217486174 -.875) ]

X₂ = 0.8998229872 - [ -0.00412824936 / -0.25325138258 ]

X₂ = 0.8835219928

X₃ = X₂ - [ sin(X₂) -(n * X₂) / cos(X₂) -n ]

X₃ = 0.8835219928 - [ {sin(0.8835219928) -(.875 * 0.8835219928)} / (cos(0.8835219928) -.875) ]

X₃ = 0.8835219928 - [ (0.7729781357 -0.77308174371) / (0.6344326613 -.875) ]

X₃ = 0.8835219928 - [ -0.00010360801 / -0.2405673387 ]

X₃ = 0.8830913110

If we were to compute a value for X₄ it would equal 0.8830910126, which shows that X₃ is accurate to six decimal places which is adequate for most practical applications.
So, now that we have determined that angle AOD equals .883091 radians ( or 50.5974 degrees), we can calculate the remaining parts of the circle.

The central angle AOB equals 2 * 50.5974 or 101.195 degrees.

The radius = line AE / sin(AOD)
radius = 7 / sin (50.5974)
radius = 9.0591
Now that we have this information, the rest of the circle can be easily solved.